# SQL - Get parameters with highest precedence

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

I have a postgreSQL table: `params` with 3 columns: `param_scope`, `param_name`, `param_value`

The format of `param_scopes` are like this: `/mainGroups/{familyId}/groups/{groupName}/groups/{subGroupName}/parameters`

or: `/mainGroups/{familyId}/groups/{groupName}/parameters`

we can have endless subgroups

I'm building a simple js function that builds a postgre SQL query which should return group parameters of higher precedence. The deeper the group is the higher precedence it has so parameters in group 2 override group1 params. However, params that are not part of group2 but included in parent scopes (so group1 in the below example) are inherited by group2.

For this I have 3 parameters that I pass to the js function: `family`, `groupId`, `precedenceList`.

The SQL query should return parameters for groups of higher precedence based on the precedence list so for example given a precedenceList of:

```js
[
  { group: 'group3', precedence: 1 },
  { group: 'group2', precedence: 2 },
  { group: 'group1', precedence: 3 }
]
```

family: `balderstone`
groupId: `group2`

And given the following DB data:

```json
[
  {
    "param_scope": "/mainGroups/balderstone/groups/group1/parameters",
    "param_name": "param1",
    "param_value": "A"
  },
  {
    "param_scope": "/mainGroups/balderstone/groups/group1/groups/group2/parameters",
    "param_name": "param1",
    "param_value": "B"
  },
  {
    "param_scope": "/mainGroups/balderstone/groups/group1/parameters",
    "param_name": "param2",
    "param_value": "false"
  },
  {
    "param_scope": "/mainGroups/balderstone/groups/group1/groups/group2/parameters",
    "param_name": "param2",
    "param_value": "true"
  },
  {
    "param_scope": "/mainGroups/balderstone/groups/group1/parameters",
    "param_name": "param3",
    "param_value": "4000"
  },
  {
    "param_scope": "/mainGroups/balderstone/groups/group1/groups/group2/groups/group3/parameters",
    "param_name": "param3",
    "param_value": "6000"
  }
]
```

the function should return a query that would return:

```json
  {
    "param_scope": "/mainGroups/balderstone/groups/group1/groups/group2/parameters",
    "param_name": "param1",
    "param_value": "B"
  },

  {
    "param_scope": "/mainGroups/balderstone/groups/group1/groups/group2/parameters",
    "param_name": "param2",
    "param_value": "true"
  },

AND!

  {
    "param_scope": "/mainGroups/balderstone/groups/group1/parameters",
    "param_name": "param3",
    "param_value": "4000"
  },
```

Because param3 is inherited from the parent group of group2 given the groupHierarchy: ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']

I can get back the results of the group2 params, my issue is with the inheritance part of the problem. Is there a way to do this in SQL (postgre)?

I tried the following so far:

```sql
SELECT 
    MAX(LEVEL) AS level,
    MAX(param_scope),
    param_name,
--  MAX(value) AS value <-- currently picks wrong value
FROM 
(
    SELECT *, 1 AS LEVEL FROM params WHERE param_scope = "/parameters"

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *, 2 AS LEVEL FROM params WHERE param_scope = "/mainGroups/balderstone/parameters"

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *, 3 AS LEVEL FROM params WHERE param_scope = "/mainGroups/balderstone/groups/group1/parameters"

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *, 4 AS LEVEL FROM params WHERE param_scope = "/mainGroups/balderstone/groups/group1/groups/group2/parameters"

) 
AS paramsPerLevel
GROUP BY param_name
```

But this doesn't return the inherited params

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the rows where deepest group ID is your specified ID (`group2`), and then include all rows where the deepest group ID is contained in the preceding scopes of the row while its `param_value` is not included in any of the prior matched rows:

```
with cte as (
   select row_number() over (order by 1) r, 
          regexp_matches(p.param_scope, '(?<=groups/)\w+', 'g') scopes, p.* 
   from params p
),
scopes as (
   select c.*, v from cte c cross join unnest(c.scopes) v
),
base as (
   select s.* from scopes s where s.param_scope ~ '(?<=mainGroups/)balderstone' 
      and s.v = (select max(s1.v) from scopes s1 where s1.r = s.r) and s.v = 'group2'
)
select b.param_scope, b.param_name, b.param_value from base b
union all
select distinct s1.param_scope, s1.param_name, s1.param_value 
from base b join scopes s on b.r = s.r and b.v != s.v 
join scopes s1 on s1.v = s.v where not exists (select 1 from base b1 where b1.param_name = s1.param_name) 
   and (select max(s2.v) from scopes s2 where s2.r = s1.r) < b.v
   and exists (select 1 from scopes s2 where s2.r = b.r and s1.v = s2.v)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JxG_ubkE)